# CXF rest service for uploading files in chunks

Tags: java, rest, cxf

I am using CXF rest services and such services for files upload:

```
   @POST
   @Path("/uploadFile")
   @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
   public Response uploadFile(List<Attachment> attachments, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
```

I want to introduce chunking to those files as they can be as big as 100MB. I dont see any options on CXF Api or I just cant find it. Is it possible with CXF?